# How to define another teaser for the second theme?

Tags: views, theming, nodes, display-suite

I have two themes: regular (1st) & mobile (2nd). Mobile theme binded with subdomain m.mysite.com.

**I can't show my mobile node teaser in mobile theme.**

I've created that teaser for mobile theme in Display Suite. Next I need to show this one in mobile theme taxonomy tag page. But I can't define theme in DS. When I use [taxonomy-term.tpl] in mobile theme to define mobile teaser, but vars doesn't works: changing $view_mode has no result (type machine name on mobile teaser), $content array is empty. I tryed to use Views, but in displays there is no options to define a theme.

What can I do? Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solves by the following:

1. Created DS template for default teaser in 2nd theme: ds-2col--node-article-teaser.tpl.php
2. Place into it code to define my new node_teaser_mobile to show:

   print render(node_view($node, $view_mode = 'node_teaser_mobile', $langcode = NULL));